# Tampermonkey vs. gmail JS API

Tags: javascript, api, gmail, tampermonkey

I am trying to use this [gmail JS tutorial](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/quickstart/js#troubleshooting) to add Email sending ability to a web page using tampermonkey. I've added the script portion directly to my tampermonkey script and dynamically inserted a DIV with the HTML via. javascript.

It does work, of sorts if I manually show the button,( and  API returns the list of labels) but it seems that the callback function (checkAuth) is not called on page load. When I inject the google script, checkAuth does not run ( have inserted console.log to confirm). Does the java script part of this tutorial need to be in a normal script element in the DOM or should I persevere ?

I understand that my TM script has it's own scope, but not sure how to add all the Google code to global scope if that is what must be done ? If I host the script on my own server will that cause problems ?

I suspect the script to add the api can not see its callback function since I defined that in the scope of the tm script.

Answer (score 1):

I think I found the general solution, add a small script that defines a global placeholder for the callback function.

Then in the TM script scope use function expression syntax for any function that requires to be in global scope.

```
var placeholder;
function TM () {
   placeHolder = function () {
      //API callback
   }
}
```